# Contents of stack trace within a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We're considering an enhancement to collect error information from our Chrome Extension that I  would like more information about.

We currently have an onError event handler that only collects file name and file number for the extension's background scripts.  This is helpful, but I would more information.

I would like to collect the message and / or the stack trace information as well, but we're concerned that the additional information (message, & stack trace), could contain sensitive user data (URL's, etc.).

Is there any user data in the stack trace or message?  (URL(s), HTTP request parms, etc.)

To be clear, in the onError event handler of the background page, we send an AJAX request to a server to log the error.

Comment: How is it possible to answer this question? It depends on the stack in question. If you're concerned about user data, scrub it before collecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally stack traces could contain sensitive data, but most of them won't. The structure of your code is what will determine this. Look at stack traces in your code and determine if you need to sanitize them.

Comment: That's what I was thought.  I haven't seen any URL information in the stack traces, but I wanted to ask.